# SwiftUI TabView and Realm: Removing first and last element doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, realm, tabview

1. We have a realm database: Album which Items.
2. We open Album in TabView and try to scroll through items and remove each Item. Moreover, we can open the Album in TabView with any current Item. For example if we clicks to 3 we open TabView where current item will be 3.
   It works well.

**The problem appears when deleting items.**
And only if we open the list of items from the end (current index 4) or from the beginning (current index 0) and immediately (without scrolling) delete the current item.
In this case, TabView does not change the current element (selection: $current) and the event onChange does not fire.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or it  is a TabView bug?

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

final class Album: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var items = RealmSwift.List<Item>()
}

final class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted(originProperty: "items") var album: LinkingObjects<Album>
    @Persisted var label: String
}

func genAlbum () -> Album {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let album = Album()
    try! realm.write {
        album.items.append(Item(value: ["label": "0"]))
        album.items.append(Item(value: ["label": "1"]))
        album.items.append(Item(value: ["label": "2"]))
        album.items.append(Item(value: ["label": "3"]))
        album.items.append(Item(value: ["label": "4"]))
        realm.add(album)
    }
    print(album)
    return album
}

let albumStore = genAlbum()


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var album = albumStore
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Count: \(self.album.items.count)")
            HStack (spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(self.album.items, id: \._id) { item in
                    Button(action: { self.selectedItem = item },
                        label: { Text("\(item.label)")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .tag(item)
                        }
                    )
                        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                        .fullScreenCover(item: self.$selectedItem, content: {
                        currentItem in
                        AlbumView(album: self.album, current: currentItem, onDismiss: { self.selectedItem = nil })
                            .background(.blue)
                            .padding()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct AlbumView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var album: Album
    @State var current: Item
    var onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $current) {
            ForEach(self.album.items, id: \._id) { item in
                Text(item.label)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .tag(item)
                    .background(.red)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .onChange(of: current) { oldCurrent, newCurrent in
            print("::::onChange current", oldCurrent.label, newCurrent.label)
        }
            .overlay(

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    let i = album.items.index(of: current)
                    Text ("overlay tab current item :\(current.label) \(i ?? -1)")
                    if let index = album.items.index(of: current) {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Delete \(index)")
                            $album.items.remove(at: index)
                            print("Items count \($album.items.count)")
                            print("Indexes \($album.items.indices)")
                        },
                            label: {
                                Text("Delete label:\(current.label)  index \(index)") }
                        ).padding().background(.red)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        if let dismiss = self.onDismiss {
                            dismiss()
                        } }, label: { Text("Close") })
                        .padding().background(.red)

                }
            }
        )

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When you delete an item, say item at index 0, can you verify it's being removed from Realm using Realm Studio?

Comment: yes, the deletion was performed but it was not cascaded
The link in the album was deleted, but the entry remained in the items

Comment: added cascadeDelete but still have the same issue ((:

Comment: I am not sure the intent of the code is clear; the vars you want to work with are Realm objects, so to observe changes in them, they should be defined as ObservedRealmObject, not a State object. That way, when they are removed or updated, the view will auto update. Or is there some other intention?

Comment: 1.    ObservedRealmObject var album: Album - it looks like you described
2.   State var current: Item -->> i think it shouldn't be ObservedRealmObject - I can’t even imagine how can feeding it to TabView with this type

Comment: Are you trying to delete the item object or simply remove it from the albums item list?

Comment: i tried different tests when i delete object or just remove it from item list. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In `AlbumView`:

```
@State var current: Item
```

should be changed to:

```
@ObservedRealmObject var current: Item
```

Comment: it can't be possible i think because we use closure:                         `.fullScreenCover(item: self.$selectedItem, content: {
                        currentItem in
                        AlbumView(album: self.album, current: currentItem, onDismiss: { self.selectedItem = nil })
                            .background(.blue)
                            .padding()
                    })`

Comment: @malhal These are Realm objects. I believe they need to be using [ObservedRealmObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#update-an-object-s-properties) so the UI updates when the underlying data on disk changes.

Comment: Think you're right, thanks!